# Windows Server 2008 shuts down after being idle for a few minutes

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

I installed Windows Server 2008 on a VMWare Host. After I have successfully booted up the server the machine suddenly, after it has been idle for about 5 minutes, shuts down.
Does anyone know if there is a specific setting I need to tweeck to prevent this shutdown when the server is idle.?

Comment: Windows Server 2008 will never shut down on it's own for being idle. Something else must have happened; live a software update; or a crash.

Comment: Check your event logs, it should be apparent if an application crash or something else is causing the shutdown.

Comment: Check your logs on both the server, and on VMWare. Update with anything that you find.

Comment: shuts down or suspends?

Comment: check the power settings within the control panel you might have an incorrect setting there.

Answer (score 0):

@Jones, the machine just shut down, no software update and no application crashed

@Dave, I checked the event logs and I can find the event that sent the signal to shut down. But it does not specify who/what sent the signal

@Nixphoe, As I mentioned above there is no specific error logged in the event log. I even had IT at work take a look at the event logs and they could not see anything abnormal.
I checked the event logs from the VMWare and I checked there is warning thrown when I start up the Windows Server VM. The event log mentions that there is insufficient video ram available. It mentions there is a max resolution and I will need to change a value:
    svga.vramSize=newValue
to increase the size.
However, I have to mention that the Windows Server does not fail to boot up and does not shut down right after the warning has been logged.

@Tony, I could not find any invalid power settings

Comment: check the esxi/esx hosts settings and or logs anything there?